# Check if DOM Element is a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I check if a given DOM element is a a checkbox.

Scenario:

I have a set of textboxes and checkboxes in which the values are assigned dynamically. I don't have a way to identify if the DOM element is a checkbox or a textbox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) pseudo-class selector along with [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if($("#that-particular-input").is(":checkbox")) {
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `:checkbox` is a pseudo-class

Answer (score 81):

Using only vanilla javascript you could do

```
if (el.type && el.type === 'checkbox') {
   ...
}
```

or even shorter

```
if ((el || {}).type === 'checkbox') {
   ...
}
```

or in modern browsers you could use `matches()`

```
if (el.matches('[type="checkbox"]') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Many years later.... you probably want to `toLowerCase` that type value, don't you?

Comment: No, please convert to `lowerCase` and compare then.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle it should depend on how you wrote the attribute in the markup, right?

Comment: You could even do `'input[type="checkbox"]'` to be safe

Answer (score 15):

Checks anything

```
function isCheckbox (element) {
   return element instanceof HTMLInputElement 
      && element.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if( $(element)[0].type == "checkbox" ) {

}
```

OR

```
if( $(element).is(':checkbox') ) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).

```
var checkboxes = $("form input:checkbox");
```

You can tell what type an input is like this:

```
if ($(".your-input").is(":text"))
{
    // Textbox
}
else if ($(".your-input").is(":checkbox"))
{
    // Checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (<DOMNode>.type === "checkbox") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
  $(element).is(':checkbox');
```

here `element` is selector to your `element`

```
if(  $(element).is(':checkbox') ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `is()`:

```
if ($el.is(':checkbox')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo-selector :checkbox with a call to jQuery's is function:

`$('#myinput').is(':checkbox')`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a decent naming convention which allows you to know if an element is a checkbox from just seeing it's id or name.
e.g. "chkMyCheckbox"