# tag type to determine if it is checkbox

Tags: jquery

Do we have anything with which we can determine the tag of checkboxes, like we have for dropdown?

```
if ($(elem).prop('tagName') == 'SELECT')
```

will it work with `onChange()` or it'll work with `onClick()` function?

suppose, I want to determine If it is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [checkbox-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

```
if ($(elem).is(':checkbox'))
```

To test whether it is a select element you can pass the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) `select` to `.is()` like

```
if ($(elem).is('select'))
```

Comment: @Suraj can you give use case... to check whether `elem` is checked, you could use `elem.checked`(if elem is a dom element reference) of `$(elem).is(':checked')` - this will work for radio and checkbox

Comment: will it work with onChange() or it'll work with onClick() function?

Comment: should work... why don't you try... if not create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: @Suraj if you want to just check whether current element is checked - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3u2wgu02/2/

Comment: It is working in the fiddle, but when I am trying the same in my code, it doesn't alert anything

Comment: @Suraj Add the script in a dom ready handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3u2wgu02/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can rather use `.is(':checkbox')`:

```
if ($(elem).is(':checkbox') ){
   //elem is checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `.is()` along with `:checkbox` selector like,

```
if ($(elem).is(':checkbox'))
```

Or you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115363/check-if-dom-element-is-a-checkbox) for doing it in different/efficient ways.

Comment: @suraj i guess you want this: `if ($(elem).is(':checkbox:checked'))`

Comment: @Suraj I think you have registered a common event handler for both select as well as for check box elements. Right?? So for that situation you can write code inside of the handler function like, `if(this.type=="checkbox") { //for checkBox } else { //for other elements }`

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'checkbox')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a jQuery object when the properties you need to use are native to the DOMElement you already have in a variable. Try this:

```
if (elem.tagName == 'INPUT' && elem.type == 'checkbox' && elem.checked) {
    // do something...
}
```